# My Ruby Program prints inspect of objects instead of defined to_s method

Tags: ruby

At the end when I try to add splat in my ruby program and print red_team does not show what I am passing but it shows the address.

Just run this piece of code on the terminal that you will come to know what I am saying. It shows me this

```
Power Rangers team: `#<Context::Player:0x0000000252c3d8>, #<Context::Player:0x0000000252c298>, #<Context::Player:0x0000000252c158>, #<Context::Player:0x0000000252c018>, #<Context::Player:0x0000000252bed8>`
```

my code:

```
        class Player
            attr_accessor :name, :age, :skill_level

            def initialize (name, age, skill_level)
                @name = name
                @age = age
                @skill_level = skill_level
            end

            def to_s
                puts "<#{@name}: #{@skill_level}(SL), #{@age}(AGE)"
            end
        end

        class Team
            include Enumerable
            attr_accessor :name, :players

            def initialize (name)
                @name = name
                @players = []
            end

            def add_players (*players)
                @players += players
            end

            def to_s
                "#{@name} team: #{@players.join(', ')}"
            end

            def each
                @players.each  {|player| yield player}
            end
        end

        player1 = Player.new("Immad", 24, 10)
        player2 = Player.new("Sharjeel", 24, 10)
        player3 = Player.new("Danish", 24, 10)
        player4 = Player.new("Ali", 24, 10)
        player5 = Player.new("Nawfil", 24, 10)

        red_team = Team.new("Power Rangers")
        red_team.add_players(player1, player2, player3, player4, player5)

        puts red_team
```

Also I have included Enumerable which is a built-in method in ruby to use select and reject at the end but I am unable to use it because it shows the address and not actually what I am passing.
Please let me know what I am doing wrong, thanks in advance.

Comment: `to_s` is supposed to return a string. Yours returns `nil`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When providing `to_s` method in Player class you're actually printing them on screen instead of returning.

Change `to_s` method in `Player` class to:

```
def to_s
  "<#{@name}: #{@skill_level}(SL), #{@age}(AGE)"
end
```

As you can see here:

```
puts "a"
a
#=> nil
```

`puts` method prints output in console and returns `nil`. If `to_s` method returns `nil` (or any non-string value), Ruby use [`Object#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-to_s) method as a fallback to provide any output. Like in this minimal example:

```
class A
  def to_s
    nil
  end
end

a = A.new 
#=> #<A:0x007fbfca06f770>

puts a
#<A:0x007fbfca06f770>
#=> nil
```

Comment: _"Ruby look for inherited to_s"_ – `puts` uses [`Object#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-to_s) as a fallback if `to_s` returns a non-string value, it doesn't traverse all ancestors.

Comment: @Immad you can accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @Esse Can ask you something?

Comment: @Immad Hamid: sure - asks

Comment: I checked your profile and found out that you are a mentor at Coders Lab. So actually you are the right person who can advice me better, I currently following this course https://www.coursera.org/specializations/ruby-on-rails , is this course right enough in order to learn ruby and ruby on rails?
After completing this course what should I do in become great in ruby and its framework rails?
Can I get your email or skype, slack, facebook or whatever where I can ask you something while learning the full stack web development.
This is mine fb.com/immadhamid1

Comment: Please send me email piotr [at] szmielew [dot] pl or twitter priv msg.

Comment: @Esse I have emailed you and I can not send you dm on twitter because for sending dm we both have to follow each other...

Comment: And thanks to you too @Stefan I didn't see your comment.